# Easy way to display a new panel with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic

I am trying to come up with the best (easiest) way to implement a sort panel slide out when a link is clicked....

Basically there is a series of divs and I would like each one to slide out a panel from the right allowing information to be added and then saved, this will then slide the panel away...

The current information is displayed (working) in the below code.  This displays 4 columns while on a PC and only 2 on a phone, which is what I would like to keep.

The premise being that if you click on Engine 1 or Engine 2 (or the actual database 'pull', then you get a page overlay that allows you to fill in a form and submit it.

I could just load another data input page, but thought this would be a bit more elegant.

The reason for the panel half way down was that I was experimenting.  Naming panels...

````
        <div class="container">
            <h2></h2>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Vessel Information for <?php echo $vesseldata['vesselTag']?></div>
                        <div class="panel-body" >
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><b>Vessel Details</b></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Type of Vessel</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $basespec['newname'];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Design Reference</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['DesignRef'];?></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Ordering Dealer</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php $OrderingDealer= array_column($OrderingDealers, 'name', 'id'); echo $OrderingDealer[$vesseldata['OrderingDealer']];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Hull Number</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['HullNo'];?></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Hull Colour</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['HullColour'];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Topside Colour</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['TopsideColour'];?></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                     <div class="row"><div><br></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><b>Build Dates</b></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Build Complete</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['BuildDate'];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Commission Complete</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['CommissionDate'];?></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                    <div class="row"><div></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><b>Build Options</b></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="engine1">Engine 1</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php $option= array_column($options, 'name', 'id'); echo $option[$vesseldata['Engine1Type']];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Engine 1 Serial</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['Engine1Number'];?></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Engine 2</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php $option= array_column($options, 'name', 'id'); echo $option[$vesseldata['Engine2Type']];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Engine 2 Serial</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['Engine1Number'];?></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Stern Drive 1</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php $option= array_column($options, 'name', 'id'); echo $option[$vesseldata['SternDrive1Type']];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Stern Drive 1 Serial</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['SternDrive1Number'];?></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Stern Drive 2</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php $option= array_column($options, 'name', 'id'); echo $option[$vesseldata['SternDrive2Type']];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Stern Drive 2 Serial</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['SternDrive2Number'];?></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Generator</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php $option= array_column($options, 'name', 'id'); echo $option[$vesseldata['Genset1Type']];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Generator Serial</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['Genset1Number'];?></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Air Conditioning</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php $option= array_column($options, 'name', 'id'); echo $option[$vesseldata['Aircon1Type']];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Air Conditioning Serial</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['Aircon1Number'];?></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Teak Pack</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php $option= array_column($options, 'name', 'id'); echo $option[$vesseldata['TeakPack']];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Teak Cork Batch</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php echo $vesseldata['TeakCorkBatch'];?></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Layout</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php $option= array_column($options, 'name', 'id'); echo $option[$vesseldata['Layout']];?></div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Interior Décor</div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><?php $option= array_column($options, 'name', 'id'); echo $option[$vesseldata['Interior']];?></div>
                                                        </div>




                                                    </div>

                                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using bootstrap, they have nice modal window module.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: thats in 4 though...  I have Bootstrap3....  Which I have also modified a little by way of fonts and spacing etc....  Not sure how easy it would be to upgrade??

Comment: But you are right, it looks like it would do the trick.....  If only there was an easy way to upgrade to 4....